# Using scanf to get a string to create and validate it against a while loop...keep getting

Tags: c, unix, scanf, c-strings

I'm creating a char* which essentially will be treated as an string. The string is suppose to be used over and over again. Everytime I'm attempting to check with the while loop and see if its correct to the "quit"...

*I keep getting a segmentation fault...What am I doing wrong -- Pretty idiotic mistake - possibly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    input = "CONTINUE";

    while(strcmp(input, "quit") != 0)
    {
            printf("%s", "System: ");
            scanf("%s", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I see in first look:

```
char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

1. You are assigning your pointer a memory of just one character. It should have enough memory to hold your string not just one character.
2. You should copy the string in to the allocated buffer using `strcpy`. Not aassign a string literal to your pointer. Note that modifying such a string literal results in **Undefined Behavior**.

   `input = "CONTINUE";`

Correct way of doing the above 2 are:

```
char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(MAX_LENGTH)); 
strcpy(input, "YOURSTRING");
```

Where `MAX_LENGTH` is sufficient to hold your input strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change a literal which is illegal.
Try:

```
char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); /* You need more than one char. */
char* input = (char*)malloc(LENGTH); /* Allocate `LENGTH` chars. */

input = "CONTINUE"; /* You can't write (scanf) over a string literal. */
strcpy(input, "CONTINUE"); /* Now it's legal to write over `input`. */
```

Other points to watch out for:

- Using `scanf` with a bare "%s" is unsafe. You should use something like `"%10s"` to make sure a potentially malicious user doesn't enter more than 10 characters
- Did you know `sizeof(char)` isn't needed since **it's guaranteed to be 1** ?

Comment: so if I did...
char* input = (char*)malloc(LENGTH); //where length was something like 80 or 100...
Then I could go on and do the while loop which would always rewrite the string?

Comment: Yup. Just don't assign "CONTINUE" or use `strcpy` like I showed you.

Comment: very nice -- thanks a lot man. Like I said, very stupid error.